# What is deciding the width of my table-column? And how to set cells scrollable vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table that is auto-generated:

```
<div id="getData" spellcheck="false"></div>

function updateDataTable(data) {

// Clear the data table.
$("#getData").empty();

// Create new data table.
$("#getData").append("<div id='resources'></div>");

// Create header for data table.
$("#resources").append("<div>" +
    "<span class='noedit'>" + "Project" + "</span>" +
    "<span class='noedit'>" + "Culture" + "</span>" +
    "<span class='noedit'>" + "Resource" + "</span>" +
    "<span class='noedit'>" + "Comments" + "</span>" +
    "</div>");

$("#getData").append("<div id='resources'></div>");
// For each item, append to data table.
$.each(data, function (i, item) {

    $("#resources").append("<div>" +
   "<span class='noedit'>" + item["Project"] + "</span>" +
   "<span class='noedit'>" + item["Culture"] + "</span>" +
   "<span>" + item["ResourceValue"] + "</span>" +
   "<span>" + item["Comments"] + "</span>" +
   "</div>");
});
```

and here is CSS for the table:

```
div#resources div > span {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

}

I'm just curious what attribute is deciding the width of each cell, because when I look at it, some columns with more content do not get more space, is there anyway to set that columns with more content get more space?

And sorry for bonus question: How to make each cell scrollable vertically? I tried

```
  overflow-y:scroll;
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Which javascript framework is this? I'll assume it's jQuery.

Comment: can't set overflow-y unless you restrict height

Comment: This isn't a table. It's spans inside a div.

Comment: @Chiperific,sorry it was my bad, I referred it as table cell since I'm using display:table-cell.

Comment: @johnwait, I'm using ajax, sorry didn't post ajax part since its not related to css.

Comment: table layout and scrolling do not go along, it is one or the other. table element(or displayed as such) shrink/expand to fit content. table-layout:fixed; can help to fix the width but it will never scroll. overflow-x will be visible or hidden y axis will expand to fit content. you need something without the table layout to scroll  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ijrwy

Comment: What if you actually switch to a table? Like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiperific/aej4wc95/2/).

Comment: So far, unless there's more CSS you haven't provided (like `div#resources div {..}`), spans will take the minimum width needed to show all the inner text, and their div container will take the full width of it's own container (since default is `display:block`). No scrolling, no vertical alignment of columns (from one row to the next). My test case: http://jsfiddle.net/xo24wehx/